# Partial Import of Snowflake into Power BI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been having issues with one particular view that I created in Snowflake; out of 38,000+ rows, when I import the view to Power BI desktop file, it only imports about 4,600 rows. I have imported other views from Snowflake to Power BI before successfully, and I already re-did the process many times and ended with the same result. The dashboard that I import this view on, I am importing another view (about 7,000 rows) and that one gets correctly imported. Has there been any issues like this before?

FYI,as additional information:
-I already have ODBC downloaded and updated. 
- when I export the result (38,000+ rows) as CSV file, it shows complete data (38,000+ rows). But when I import (not direct queries) to Power BI desktop, it only downloads about 4,600 rows with NO error.

Comment: How many rows do you see in the Snowflake History tab?

Comment: Also check if you have a powerbi relationship that is constraining your results.

Comment: Does Power BI have a maximum query size or perhaps a temporary storage space it allocates for this procedure?  Wondering if you are running out of temp space. You could also try testing from Excel or Tableau or another application.